# How to connect the printer HP 2575 to a network?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, printer

I have 2 PCs and a router and I want to connect my HP 2575 to this network. 
So, I found a network cable and I connected the printer to the router. I access the router and I can see that the printer is connected.

My question is: How can I use the printer, from one of my computer. I tried Add Printer feature, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Peter, what OS(s) are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Some HP printers will include a network setup tool with the driver CD.  Check for that to start.

You should assign assign an IP to the printer either statically or by reservation on the DHCP server.  You can then add that IP as a port in the "add printer" wizard in XP.  Select a local printer and then select Create a new port.  You may be able to use HP Standard TCP/IP port or TCP/IP port.  The wizard will attempt to connect to the device. You will have to do this for all systems.

Comment: The HP driver does not need a static or reserved IP

Comment: @Shevek - I've used you method and had success, but I also had 1 computer that installed a copy of the printer randomly when it booted. That resulted in print documents going to an inactive printer and the user clicking the Print button repeatedly. Gave up and assigned a static IP an the problem was resolved. I know it's not required, but it is reliable.

Comment: @Shevek. I suggest that one should assign a static IP or reservation as a best practice. If you are printing to an IP address and that address changes, the chances of printing are somewhat less.  Can you explain how the device handles an IP change?

Comment: It's been a while since I connected mine up via LAN (I now use USB as the card reader shows up as a Windows removable drive) but I recall the driver installs an HP custom printer port which uses the device ID (possibly the MAC address) not the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the most reliable way is to assign a fixed IP to the printer then add a Local printer. Click Next and choose to create a new port, type **Standard TCP/IP Port**. Click Next a couple of times then enter the printer's IP address and give the port a name.

Comment: The HP driver does not need a fixed IP

Comment: @Shevek - it doesn't _need_ a fixed IP, but things tend to work better that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same printer.

If you download and install the HP driver package (either [Basic Print and Scan Driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=mp-41971-2&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=228&product=441240) at 70mb or [Full Feature Software and Drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=mp-42045-2&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=228&product=441240) at 507mb) the installer will detect the printer on the network and set up everything for  you.

These links are for XP as you specified, XP 64 bit drivers are different